# jQuery .load() codeigniter page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to build an Ajax suggestion feature within codeigniter using jQuery. However, when I am using the .load() function within jQuery I cannot find a way to call the controller, I am calling it as so:

`$("#sugresultcontain").load('http://localhost/ajaxtest/suggest #loadsuggest');`

However, the content does not load. I then tried to use:

`$("#sugresultcontain").load('http://localhost/ajaxtest/application/views/ajaxref/suggest.php #loadsuggest');`

And as expected, again this did not work as I need to make a call to the controller and not just the view itself.

So my question is, how can I use the .load() AJAX function to call to the controller that outputs suggest.php.

If more detail is needed, please just ask.

Comment: What errors are you seeing if you visit the url directly?

Comment: I truly apologise, I feel like an idiot. I had spent the whole evening last night trying to get this to work, I had accidentally left out the class. the dir 'ajaxtest' is the app base... I should have used - 'http://localhost/ajaxtest/ajaxhandle/suggest.

Comment: Yes, I feel stupid but it is finally working.

Comment: @DominicSore: Please post your solution (and mark it as accepted) for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

When you are having problems with AJAX requests, you can see server's response

- in Google Chrome and in Internet Explorer by pressing F12 on tab
  Network
- in Firefox by pressign CTRL+Shift+K

If you have allowed displaying errors, it will be there.